# How can I use metrics-server instead of heapster to see CPU usage in HPA

Tags: kubernetes, cpu-usage, missing-data, autoscaling, azure-aks

How can I set to use metrics-server to get CPU usage for HPA?

```
# kubectl top nodes
```

> error: metrics not available yet

```
# kubectl get pods -n kube-system
```

> NAME READY STATUS RESTARTS AGE
>
> heapster-709db6bd48-f2gba 2/2 Running 0 6h
>
> metrics-server-70647b8f8b-99pja 1/1 Running 0 5h
>
> .....

```
# kubectl get hpa
```

> NAME                REFERENCE                      TARGETS         MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
>
> devops-deployment   Deployment/devops-deployment   <unknown>/50%   4         10        4          1h

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you.
What helped me is [this post](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server/issues/131#issuecomment-418405881).

-remove metrics-server

-change metrics-server/deploy/1.8+/metrics-server-deployment.yaml

-apply again

-or simply

Below more details:

```
kubectl delete -f metrics-server/deploy/1.8+
```

Edit `metrics-server/deploy/1.8+/metrics-server-deployment.yaml` and add next options:

```
    command:
    - /metrics-server
    - --kubelet-insecure-tls
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
```

metrics-server-deployment.yaml should look like below, or simply copy paste it from [here](https://github.com/juan-vg/metrics-server/blob/264f9c551abdeedc575d36e74da40671c51cb747/deploy/1.8%2B/metrics-server-deployment.yaml)

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: metrics-server
  template:
    metadata:
      name: metrics-server
      labels:
        k8s-app: metrics-server
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: metrics-server
      volumes:
      # mount in tmp so we can safely use from-scratch images and/or read-only containers
      - name: tmp-dir
        emptyDir: {}
      containers:
      - name: metrics-server
        image: k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server-amd64:v0.3.1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command:
        - /metrics-server
        - --kubelet-insecure-tls
        - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: tmp-dir
          mountPath: /tmp
```

Apply metrics-server files again: `kubectl apply -f metrics-server/deploy/1.8+`

> clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:aggregated-metrics-reader
>   created
>   clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/metrics-server:system:auth-delegator
>   created
>   rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/metrics-server-auth-reader
>   created apiservice.apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io
>   created serviceaccount/metrics-server created
>   deployment.extensions/metrics-server created service/metrics-server
>   created clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:metrics-server
>   created
>   clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:metrics-server
>   created

And check result:

```
kubectl get hpa    
NAME               REFERENCE                     TARGETS         MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
nginx-deployment   Deployment/nginx-deployment   <unknown>/80%   3         10        10         25

kubectl top nodes
NAME            CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%   
kube-master-1   255m         12%    2582Mi          35%       
kube-worker-1   124m         6%     2046Mi          27

kubectl top pods
NAME                                CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)   
nginx-deployment-76bf4969df-4bbdc   0m           2Mi             
nginx-deployment-76bf4969df-5m6xc   0m           2Mi             
nginx-deployment-76bf4969df-b4zh7   0m           2Mi             
nginx-deployment-76bf4969df-c58wl   0m           2Mi             
nginx-deployment-76bf4969df-cktcg   0m           2Mi             
nginx-deployment-76bf4969df-fbjj9   0m           2Mi             
nginx-deployment-76bf4969df-gh94w   0m           2Mi             
nginx-deployment-76bf4969df-qx6ld   0m           2Mi             
nginx-deployment-76bf4969df-rvt54   0m           2Mi             
nginx-deployment-76bf4969df-vq9gs   0m           2Mi
```

Additionally, if you are using autoscaling on a pod based on percent utilization of resources, the pod needs to have a resource limit provided, or else it will be unable to calculate the percentage of resources in use. In the absence of resource limits on the pod spec for a deployment, you will need to set you HPA to scale based on absolute values, with units included. In the case of CPU, you might set it to `300m` as a string. In the case of RAM, you might set it to `400Mi`, for example. The lack of a resource limit would explain why you don't see a `current` value for the metric when you run `kubectl get hpa` under `TARGETS`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your steps but still show <unknown> under Targets column (like your last result shown) even I have waited for few days. may I know how to not show <known> but actual value? thanks.